Valve or Pipeline rate setting via scheduling
im fairly new to Anylogic and i´m trying to model a solar energy production system using the fluid library, all is well until i wanted to limit my power demand for a certain time during the day (reduction of computation power during the night), i couldn´t find a tutorial online, through some research i´ve found that i need to use either schedule or event from the agent menu, however i couldnt figure out what code to write in the actions window as i dont know the names of the variable and methods i should use.
in short i want to modify a valves´ output rate from 100% to 70% from 10pm to 6am
can anyone help
just tried different variable names and methods but none worked


in short i want to modify a valves´ output rate from 100% to 70% from 10pm to 6am

Add an event to trigger first at 10pm of the first day, then cyclic every 24 hrs.
In the action code, write myValve.set_openRate(...) with whatever 70% means to you.
Do the same with another event to set it back to whatever 100% means to you.
You can always find all possible functions in the help and via code-complete (also see the help for that).
